# Replace forEach google script

Tags: loops, for-loop, google-apps-script, foreach, break

I want to replace the forEach function for me to break the code in case i don't have a customer with an order.

Current code:

```
customers.forEach(function (customer) 
{
  ss.toast(`Creating Invoice for ${customer.name}`, APP_TITLE, 1);
  let invoice = createInvoiceForCustomer(
    customer, products, transactions, invoiceTemplateSheet, ss.getId());
  invoices.push(invoice);
});
```

Code I'm trying to make:

```
    for (var i=1 ; i<=custlastrow ; i++)
  {
    if (customers.ordenes == "No")
    {
      continue; // Skip current iteration... 
    }
    do the other part
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

To make life easier, you could add a filter before, meaning you can leave the `forEach`.

Like this:

```
const customersWithOrders = customers.filter(customer => customer.ordenes !== "No")

customersWithOrders.forEach(....
```

I find that using `continue` in loops can lead to messy code. IMO the above is easier to read.